# How can I make more than 4 partitions in a hard disk?

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu in 3 partitions and I want to install it in an empty space, but I can't;  I think I must to do more partitions.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/ and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/partitions.html

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

The non-allocated space is outside of your 4th primary partition and you can only have four!

So you should:

- Boot from the Ubuntu LiveDVD
- Choose <kbd>Try Ubuntu</kbd>
- Start `gparted` from Dash menu.
- Extend `sda4` to the end of your disk
- create a new partition in the empty space
- Install it there!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: You do not need to install gparted when boot from LiveCD. it is already there. And you need to run `sudo gparted` if it is started from terminal.

Comment: Depends...  On 12.04 Last time I looked, it wasn't on the distro (things might have changed in the mean time) Thanks for the edit!

Comment: It is not included in the installed distro but it is always there on LiveCD.